# Which .NET Core SDK to use for .NET Core 2.2 in VS 16.4?

Tags: .net-core

As of today (December 2019), which of the following .NET Core SDK-s should I use for targeting .NET Core 2.2 in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4?

a) SDK 2.2.207, released on 19 November 2019, supporting Visual Studio 2019 v16.0

b) SDK 2.2.402, released on 10 September 2019, supporting Visual Studio 2019 v16.2

I guess I should use SDK 2.2.207, so I can use the latest runtime (2.2.8), but what puzzles me is why it was not updated automatically by Visual Studio Update? (after updating to Visual Studio 16.4, I currently have the following SDK-s installed: 3.1.100, 2.2.402, 2.1.802)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use any SDK that vs will choose, but should stick to the lastest ones if possible to ensure you don't get compiler mismatches (e.g. when you pin the SDK for command-line builds but want to use newer compiler features).

You can build 2.2 applications with the 3.* SDKs as well, the older SDK version however are still maintained for compatibility.

Do note that .NET Core 2.2 will go out of service no December 23rd 2019 so i suggest migrating to a higher version or the 2.1 LTS version. Likely for this reason, there was no additional 2.2.403 release.